# Feature extraction from each Bounding Box

Tags: computer-vision

I have bounding box for each training image. Now I want to extract feature from each bounding box but not from entire image. Could someone kindly help me to do it? I will be very grateful to him.

Answer (score 0):

Just save the bounding box in a separate image. If you are using opencv , see [how to set roi in an](http://answers.opencv.org/question/10364/set-roi-in-cvmat/) image. Now extract feature on the image containing only the portion in the bounding box.

Comment: Thanks. I can do it easily. But The size of box is not fixed. In different images have different size boxes. So my features dimension for different boxes are different. But to use classifier I need fixed dimension features. How to get it? Please help me.

Comment: Use the dimension of the box for normaisation. The process of normalisation depends on the specific feature.